# fetch_sub with memory_order_relaxed for atomic reference counting?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

```
std::atomic<int> cnt = {2};

thread 1:
    doFoo();
    if (cnt.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1) {
      doBazz();
    }

thread 2:
    doBar();
    if (cnt.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1) {
        doBazz();
    }
```

Can we guarantee `doFoo()` and `doBar()` always happen before `doBazz()`?

Comment: You're using memory_order_relaxed, which means that there is no memory ordering performed. There is no such guarantee.

Answer (score -1):

If **thread 2** calls `doBazz()` it is guaranteed that `doBazz()` sees all the side effects of `doBar()` because they run on the same thread and there is *sequenced-before* relationship between them. But it is not guaranteed that it sees side effects of `doFoo()` or that `doFoo()` has been called at all. It is because there is no *happens-before* relationship formed between `doFoo()` and `doBazz()`. This relationship would be formed if **thread 1** decreased `cnt` using `std::memory_order_release` and **thread 2** used `std::memory_order_acquire` when accessing `cnt`, which would create a synchronization point between them.

It is symmetrical for the case when **thread 1** calls `doBazz()`.

So, using `cnt.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel)` (`std::memory_order_acq_rel` combines both `std::memory_order_acquire` and `std::memory_order_release`) in both threads would provide the guarantee you are asking about.

We could also use `cnt.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release)` and call `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire)` just before calling `doBazz()` to achieve the same.

Answer (score -2):

There is no memory ordering at all in the code you've shown, so that guarantee does *not* hold true. However it is possible to use relaxed ordering where you are and have it work, by making `fetch_sub` part of a [release sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release_sequence):

```
std::atomic<int> cnt{0};
cnt.store(2, std::memory_order_release); // initiate release sequence (RS)

//thread 1:
    doFoo();
    if (cnt.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1) { // continue RS
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire); // synchronizes with RS
        doBazz();
    }

//thread 2:
    doBar();
    if (cnt.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1) { // continue RS
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire); // synchronizes with RS
        doBazz();
    }
```

or

```
void doBazz();

std::atomic<int> cnt{0};
cnt.store(2, std::memory_order_release); // initiate release sequence (RS)

//thread 1:
    doFoo();
    if (cnt.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1) { // continue RS
        doBazz();
    }

//thread 2:
    doBar();
    if (cnt.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1) { // continue RS
        doBazz();
    }

void doBazz() {
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire); // synchronizes with RS
    // ...
}
```

These guarantee that `doFoo()` and `doBar()` always happen before `doBazz()`.

Comment: Acquire doesn't prevent code moving below the operation.

Comment: I don't see how you prevent that.

Comment: @2501 : In the C++ memory model, every non-relaxed atomic operation acts as a compiler barrier.

Comment: That is not correct. Acquire only acts as a barrier preventing moving code above it. And vice-versa for release. You need a *full* barrier to prevent code from moving both ways.

Comment: @2501 : Citation needed. Jeff Preshing certainly disagrees with you.

Comment: Shouldn't you provide a citation supporting your answer?

Comment: @2501 : I don't have the standard handy at the moment (on mobile), but I can quote  someone authoritative: "*`atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire/release)` ... prevents compiler reordering of neighboring instructions*" — Preshing's blog.

Comment: Here is a quote from [Jeff](http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/#IDComment721195803):  *Acquire semantics prevent memory reordering of the read-acquire with any read or write operation which **follows** it in program order.* Acquire doesn't do the same for code preceding it, you need a release for that.

Comment: @2501 : Gotta go, feel free to write your own (presumably more-correct) answer!

Comment: I think you should be responsible and either fix or delete the incorrect answer.

Comment: @2501 : I don't think it's incorrect, you do; the burden is on you to prove it wrong. One last copy/paste since it was in my buffer: ["*In the new C++11 (formerly known as C++0x) atomic library standard, every non-relaxed atomic operation acts as a compiler barrier as well.*"](http://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/)

Comment: Yes that quote is correct, however not every atomic operation acts as a **full** barrier. This is the relevant difference you not seeing. An acquire operation has specific semantics I quoted earlier. It is a barrier? Yes. Is it a full barrier? No. Please read this: http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/#IDComment721195803 and watch this: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2

Answer (score -2):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

Even with relaxed memory model, out-of-thin-air values are not allowed to circularly depend on their own computations, for example, with x and y initially zero,

```
// Thread 1:
r1 = x.load(memory_order_relaxed);
if (r1 == 42) y.store(r1, memory_order_relaxed);
// Thread 2:
r2 = y.load(memory_order_relaxed);
if (r2 == 42) x.store(42, memory_order_relaxed);
```

is not allowed to produce r1 == r2 == 42 since the store of 42 to y is only possible if the store to x stores 42, which circularly depends on the store to y storing 42. Note that until C++14, this was technically allowed by the specification, but not recommended for implementors.

Even with memory_order_relaxed, there is still some execution order not allowed. It appears to me that

```
cnt.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) == 2
```

should happen before

```
cnt.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1
```

right? And therefore both doFoo() and doBar() should happen before doBazz().